# Sorting by counting the intersection of two lists in MongoDB

Tags: sorting, mongodb, mapreduce

We have a posting analyzing requirement, that is, for a specific post, we need to return a list of posts which are mostly related to it, the logic is comparing the count of common tags in the posts. For example:

```
    postA = {"author":"abc",
        "title":"blah blah",
        "tags":["japan","japanese style","england"],
    }
```

there are may be other posts with tags like:

```
postB:["japan", "england"]
postC:["japan"]
postD:["joke"]
```

so basically, postB gets 2 counts, postC gets 1 counts when comparing to the tags in the postA. postD gets 0 and will not be included in the result.

My understanding for now is to use map/reduce to produce the result, I understand the basic usage of map/reduce, but I can't figure out a solution for this specific purpose.

Any help? Or is there a better way like custom sorting function to work it out? I'm currently using the pymongodb as I'm python developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an index on tags:

```
db.posts.ensure_index([('tags', 1)])
```

and search for posts that share at least one tag with postA:

```
posts = list(db.posts.find({_id: {$ne: postA['_id']}, 'tags': {'$in': postA['tags']}}))
```

and finally, sort by intersection in Python:

```
key = lambda post: len(tag for tag in post['tags'] if tag in postA['tags'])
posts.sort(key=key, reverse=True)
```

Note that if postA shares at least one tag with a large number of other posts this won't perform well, because you'll send so much data from Mongo to your application; unfortunately there's no way to sort and limit by the size of the intersection using Mongo itself.